# How to compare column from a file c++

Tags: c++, compare

I have a file that has 3 columns with many rows. I want to compare the value either increase or decrease for 2 columns. But when I compare, the value always increases even it should be decreased. Any idea how to solve this? This is my coding to compare the value in the file. But I didn't get the desired output. anyone can help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

ifstream fromFile;  
fromFile.open("data.txt");
{
    cout << "There was an error" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

else   
  cout << "No error, file opened successfully" << endl;
   

    fromFile.clear();
    fromFile.seekg(0);

    for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)
   {        

    int a{}, b {}, c {};
    fromFile >> a >> b >> c ;
   
    cout<<"  Year : " <<a<<" population : "<<b<<" car : "<<c<< endl;

    if ( b < b && c < c )

    cout << " population decrease and car production decrease " << endl;

    if ( b > b && c > c );
     cout << " population increase and car production increase " << endl;
    
    if ( b > b && c < c )

    cout << " population increase but car production decrease " << endl;

    if ( b < b && c > c );
     cout << " population decrease but car production increase " << endl;
    }

//CLOSES FILES
fromFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing variables against themselves... `if ( b < b && c < c )`

Comment: Please add a sample input file to your [mre] and show the desired output for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. I will first mention those and then show a corrected solution (one of many possible variants).

Some issues:

- You should not use `using namespace std`. There are many expanations on *stackoverflow* with the explanation. Use full qualified names instead
- The `std::ifstream` has a constructor that automatically opens the stream. No need for function `open`
- The stream has an overloaded [bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) operator. You can simply test the state with `if (fromFile)`
- You forgot the `if` statement, but have an `else` statement. So, your program will not compile. And is logically wrong
- Because of the missing `if` the program will always exit immidiately
- `clear` and `seekg` are not necessary. The filepointer is at the beginning after opening the stream.
- You use a loop with fixed hardcoded magic number 20. What if the file has more or less rows? You need to use the condition end-of-file to end the loop
- You compare always the variables with itself. Even the compiler will warn you. This cannot work. You need to read a variable, store it somewhere in a different variable, read again from the file and compare the current variable with the previous value. This is your *main* problem
- No need to call the `close`-function of the stream. The destructor will call it implicitely for you, when the stream variable leaves its scope
- You have not enough comparision `if` statements. Many cases, especially, if values are same than before, will not be handled

So, what do we need to do? I will explain with only one variable now. Let's take the year. We define a variable `year` and a second varibale `previousValueYear`. In a loop, we read the value from the file into `year`. Then, we compare the `year` variable with the `previousValueYear`, do the evaluation and show the output. And then, before reading the next value from the file, we copy the current value from `year` to `previousValueYear`. Then we can do the correct comparison in the next loop run.

The first comparision is a little bit tricky, because we do not have a `previousValueYear`. We will add an additional `if` statement with a boolean flag, to check for this condition.

Please see here the corrected version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    // Open the source file
    std::ifstream fromFile("data.txt");

    // Check, if we could open the file
    if (fromFile) {    // bool operator of stream will be called

        // OK, file could be opened. Defineour variables
        int year{}, population{}, car{};
        int previousValueYear{}, previousValuePopulation{}, previousValueCar{};
        bool thisIsTheNotFirstLoopRun{};

        // Read values in a loop and check, if the input worked
        while (fromFile >> year >> population >> car) {

            // Show read data
            std::cout << "Year: " << year << " \tPopulation: " << population << " \tCar: " << car << '\n';

            // In the first loop run, we will not do a comparision (There is only one value and nothing to compare
            if (thisIsTheNotFirstLoopRun) {

                // Do the comparisons
                if ((population < previousValuePopulation) and (car < previousValueCar))
                    std::cout << "Population decrease and car production decrease\n";

                if ((population > previousValuePopulation) and (car > previousValueCar))
                    std::cout << "Population increase and car production increase\n";

                if ((population > previousValuePopulation) and (car < previousValueCar))
                    std::cout << "Population increase and car production decrease\n";

                if ((population < previousValuePopulation) and (car > previousValueCar))
                    std::cout << "Population decrease and car production increase\n";
            }

            // Remember current values for next loop run
            previousValueYear = year;
            previousValuePopulation = population;
            previousValueCar = car;

            // Now, we will not have any longer the first loop run
            thisIsTheNotFirstLoopRun = true;
        }

    } 
    else {
        // Error, file could not be opened. Show message
        std::cerr << "\nError: SourceFile could not be opened\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Advanced C++ porgrammers would change a lot. But for now it is OK